# HQL - How can I use multiple join?

Tags: join, hql, subquery

I have two classes called "Block" and "Building", as the following:

```
class Block {
  Block parent;
  Set<Block> children;
}

class Building {
   Block block;
}
```

Now I have a Block object and want to find all Buildings which associate with this Block or any of its children, or any of its grand children,...

Can someone give me a HQL hint?

Comment: first, class Block, IMHO, must a set of Building and no Block

Comment: I explained my problem with a simple case to find the solution as soon as possible, so the above example is just demonstrates my problem and is not real. Please help me the solution with the above case